# Unable to upload cookbooks to my server using Chef workstation using Knife - CHEF

Tags: chef-infra

I'm unable to upload my cookbooks from my Chef workstation using

```
knife cookbook upload <cookbook_name>.
```

It is throwing me error saying

```
Could not find cookbook <cookbook_name> in your cookbook path, skipping it. 
Uploaded 0 cookbook.
```

All my cookbooks are in my local. I can see my cookbooks when I "ls" it. In the knife.rb file the path is set to `["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]`. Please help me I'm stuck.

PS: "" were not used except in path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use cookbook name and remove the path format.

```
knife cookbook upload 7-zip-1.0.2
```

Comment: I think you might have done the Bad Thing where you try to use the Berkshelf cookbooks folder as your cookbook path. Don't do that, it is very fragile and we intend to break it eventually.

Comment: 'C:\Users\..\..\..\..\chef-starter\chef-repo\cookbooks' This is my path where the cookbook(s) are located in my local & in my 'knife.rb' file the cookbook_path is set to '["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]' @coderanger

Comment: Vamsi Sorry, the comment was directed at @AmmY.

Comment: Please download fresh chef DK

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a cookbook named `7-zip-1.0.2`? I would expect it to be named `7-zip` or `seven_zip` (the latter is the normal community cookbook for 7-Zip. Probably just fix the name you're using.